# display 3 months calendar with previous and next arrows at the top using calendar library codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, calendar

[The below image is the pictorial representation of what I am trying to get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uau3i.png)

My Code:

application/controllers/DatePic_Controller.php

In controller , build_display() function is called with month and year as parameters . This month and year is passed to the generate function of the model file , where we call the generate function of the codeigniter calendar library.

```
public function index() {

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$month2_year = date("Y",strtotime("+1 month"));
//echo 'month2_year:'.$month2_year;
$month2_month = date("m",strtotime("+1 month"));
//echo 'month2_month:'.$month2_month;


$month3_year = date("Y",strtotime("+2 month"));
//echo 'month2_year:'.$month2_year;
$month3_month = date("m",strtotime("+2 month"));

$cal_data['month1'] = $this->build_display($year,$month);

//print_r($cal_data['month1']);

$cal_data['month2'] = $this->build_display($month2_year, $month2_month);
//print_r($cal_data['month2']);

$cal_data['month3'] = $this->build_display($month3_year, $month3_month);

$this->load->view('calendar_view', $cal_data);
}


public function build_display($year,$month){

    //ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $this->load->model("DatePic_model");


    if($day = $this->input->post('day')){

        $this->DatePic_model->add_calendar_data("$year-$month-$day",$this->input->post('data'));
    } 

    $calendar = $this->DatePic_model->generate($year,$month);
    //print_r($calendar);
    //echo $calendar_view = $this->load->view("datepic_view",$data,true);

     return $calendar; 
}
```

application/models/DatePic_model.php

In model , I have used the conf variable to store calendar preferences and template.

In addition , I have used get_calendar_data() , to display the holiday of the corresponding date in the calendar itself.But its not working.....

```
public function  __construct(){



    $this->conf = array(
                'start_day' => 'monday',
                'show_next_prev' => true,
                'next_prev_url' => 'http://localhost/STUDY/CI_Mini_Projects/DatePic_Controller/display',
                'day_type' => 'short'
    );

    $this->conf['template'] = '


    {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

    {heading_row_start}<tr class="heading">{/heading_row_start}

    {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
    {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
    {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

    {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

    {week_row_start}<tr class="weekdays">{/week_row_start}
    {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
    {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

    {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
    {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}
    {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
    {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}

    {cal_cell_content}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
        <div class="content">{content}</div>
    {/cal_cell_content}
    {cal_cell_content_today}
        <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
        <div class="content">{content}</div>
    {/cal_cell_content_today}

    {cal_cell_no_content}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cell_no_content}
    {cal_cell_no_content_today}
        <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cell_no_content_today}

    {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

    {cal_cell_other}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cel_other}

    {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
    {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
    {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
    {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

    {table_close}</table>{/table_close}

    ';

}


public function get_calendar_data($year,$month){

    $query = $this->db->select('date,data')->from('holiday')->like('date',"$year-$month",'after')->get();
    //SELECT date,data FROM holiday WHERE date LIKE '2019-04%'; ==>     2019-04-19   Nineteen

    $cal_data = array();

    foreach($query->result() as $row){

        $cal_data[substr($row->date,8,2)] = $row->data;

        //2019-04-19 : 19
    }
    print_r($cal_data);
    //return $cal_data;

    /* If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are ‘before’, ‘after’, ‘none’ and ‘both’ (which is the default).

    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');    // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match' ESCAPE '!'
    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after');     // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match%' ESCAPE '!'
    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none');      // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match' ESCAPE '!'
    $this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both');      // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%' ESCAPE '!' */



}

public function add_calendar_data($date,$data){


    if($this->db->select('date')->from('holiday')->where('date',$date)->count_all_results()){

        $this->db->where('date',$date)
                        ->update('holiday',array(
                                'date'=>$date,
                                'data'=>$data));
        echo "update";                      

    }else{

    $this->db->insert('holiday',array(
                                'date'=>$date,
                                'data'=>$data));
    }

    echo "insert";
}

public function generate($year,$month){


    $this->load->library("calendar",$this->conf);

    /* $cal_data = array(
                15 => base_url().'User_Controller/create_user',
                17 => base_url().'role'
    ); */

    //$cal_data = $this->add_calendar_data('2019-03-04','foo');

    $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year,$month);
    //print_r($cal_data);
    return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$cal_data);
}
```

application/views/calendar_view.php

This is the view file

```js
<script src= base_url()."/assets/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.calendar .day').click(function(){
  day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
  
  //alert(day_num);
  day_data = prompt('Enter Stuff',$(this).find('.content').html());
  if(day_data !=null){
   
   $.ajax({
     url:window.location,
     type:'POST',
     data:{
      day:day_num,
      data:day_data      
     },
     success:function(msg){
      location.reload();
      
     }
    
   });
  }
  
  
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
.calendar{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:12px;
}
table.calendar{
 
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
.calendar .days td{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border:2px solid black;
 padding:4px;
 vertical-align:top;
 background-color:#DEF;
 
}

.calendar .days td:hover{

 background-color:#FFF;
 
}

.calendar .weekdays td{
 
 border:2px solid black;
 padding:2px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color : #C0C0C0;
}

.calendar .heading th{
 
 text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px; 
 padding:10px;
 
}

.calendar .highlight{
 
 font-weight:bold;
 color:blue; 
}

.calendar .content{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="month1">
<?=$month1; ?>
</div>

<div id="month2">
<?=$month2; ?>
</div>

<div id="month3">
<?=$month3; ?>
</div>
```

[I have shared the output display I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C33fU.png)

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I am trying to develop three months calendar ** with next and prev on the top , not for each month** .So that , when user clicks the prev button on the top , previous three months can be displayed and when the user clicks the next button , next three months should be displayed.

Comment: Which three months?

Comment: From the current month , i.e [March-May 2019] , On clicking Prev Button , months from [Jan - Feb 2019]  should be displayed, On clicking Next button , months from [June-Aug 2019] should be displayed.

Comment: ok and currently which issue you are facing to do this?

Comment: From image 1 [The below image is the pictorial representation of what I am trying to get.] , on clicking the previous arrow , the last 3 months [Dec 2018-Feb 2019] must be displayed.On clicking the next arrow , the next 3 months [June 2019 - Aug 2019] should be displayed.I am using ajax on click of previous and next arrows.What  I need to write inside ajax and what data I need to pass

Comment: your requirement and issue with your code is not getting clear.